# Unchecked checkbox when another is checked in magento2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, checkbox

I created two checkboxes i magento checkout in billing address section. Checkboxes name "Firma" and "Osoba prywatna". My custom module allow me to create only checkboxes but I would like to uncheck "firma" checkbox when i check "osoba prywatna" checkbox and the other way too.
[image: example]

I was trying use jquery code but it's not working.

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function() { 
        $('[name="custom_attributes[faktura_os_prywatna]"]').prop('checked', true);
            $('[name="custom_attributes[is_business_account]"], [name="custom_attributes[faktura_os_prywatna]"]').on('change', function() {
                $('[name="custom_attributes[is_business_account]"], [name="custom_attributes[faktura_os_prywatna]"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
            });
        });
    });
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: why not use radio buttons instead?

Answer (score 0):

I set timeout and now it's working fine

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function ($) {

    setTimeout(function () {

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('Working');
            $('#checkmo').prop('checked', true);
            $('[name="custom_attributes[faktura_os_prywatna]"]').prop('checked', true);
            $('[name="custom_attributes[is_business_account]"], [name="custom_attributes[faktura_os_prywatna]"]').on('change', function () {
                $('[name="custom_attributes[is_business_account]"], [name="custom_attributes[faktura_os_prywatna]"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```